# Why Firebase Task in RxJava Completable emitter doesn't execute?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java2

I'm developing a Firebase Android application which connect to a Firestore. The nomenclature is that the collection is "Assets". The example code had simple actions like `addAsset` and `deleteAsset`, those work fine. This is the data repository layer which actually converse with Firebase, the view model layer is above this.

```
class FirestoreAssetRepository(secondaryDB: FirebaseFirestore) : IAssetRepository {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "FirestoreAssetRepo"
        private const val ASSET_COLLECTION = "Assets"
    }

    private var remoteDB: FirebaseFirestore
    private var changeObservable: Observable<List<DocumentSnapshot>>

    init {
        remoteDB = secondaryDB
    }

    override fun addAsset(asset: Asset): Completable {
        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            remoteDB.collection(ASSET_COLLECTION)
                .add(mapToAssetData(asset))
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onComplete()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onError(it)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    override fun deleteAsset(assetId: String): Completable {
        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            remoteDB.collection(ASSET_COLLECTION)
                .document(assetId)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onComplete()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onError(it)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

I'm adding an action to the repository which would modify a specific document.

```
    override fun lockUnlockAsset(assetId: String): Completable {
        Log.d(TAG, "lockUnlockAsset")
        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            remoteDB.collection(ASSET_COLLECTION)
                .document(assetId)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unlocking")
                    val remoteAsset = mapDocumentToRemoteAsset(it)
                    it.reference.update(getUnlockLocation())
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onComplete()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Could not find asset to unlock")
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onError(it)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

The execution reaches `Log.d(TAG, "lockUnlockAsset")` but never gets to `Log.d(TAG, "Unlocking")`. If I place a break point at that second logging command it is the usual red dot in the beginning, but when the call comes into the function the icon changes to a grey "don't enter" icon and when I hover over it Android Studio tells me that "No executable found at ...". So something is definitely wrong there.

[image]

I'm new to Kotlin and RxJava2. How can I get this to work?

---

Update: to answer Pavel's question: these functions are called from the ViewModel layer:

```
fun deleteAsset(assetId: String) {
    repository.deleteAsset(assetId)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            {},
            {
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
        .addTo(disposable)
}

fun addAsset(assetTitle: String) {
    repository.addAsset(Asset("${System.currentTimeMillis()}", assetTitle))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            {},
            {
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
        .addTo(disposable)
}

fun lockUnlockAsset(assetId: String) {
    repository.lockUnlockAsset(assetId)
}
```

I was experimenting with combinations of `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observe` at the repository level. Maybe it's the `.addTo(disposable)` which got it working, I'm not sure what I was missing. Now it's working, I wait for Pavel for his answer.

Comment: Has your failure listener been called? If yes, what's the error there? If not, maybe you didn't subscribe to the `Completable`?

Comment: @xizzhu The `addOnFailureListener` has a debug log statement and I don't see that in the logs either. It's weird why Android Studio reports my inner instructions to be "No executable found". I think I may miss either some stuff like I'd have to have an extra observer or listener chained onto the emitter to like make it work. Or some other systemic problem. But the `addAsset` and `deleteAsset` works.

Comment: can you show how you execute the `lockUnlockAsset()` Completable, i guess you are not subscribed

Comment: @PavelPoley I was experimenting with `observeOn` and follow-up chain calls but I was missing something and your question encouraged me to look at that area more. I'll complete my question with those code sections. So now it's working: I was missing a chain call of `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe({}, { it.printStackTrace() }).addTo(disposable)` on the ViewModel level where I call the repository function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with combinations of `.subscribeOn(...)` and `observeOn(..)` + `.observe(...)` at the data repository level, but I should have just followed the pattern in the view model (view model calls the functions of the data repository): it's a chained `subscribeOn` + `subscribe` + `addTo(disposable)`:

```
fun lockUnlockAsset(assetId: String) {
    repository.lockUnlockAsset(assetId)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            {},
            {
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
        .addTo(disposable)
}
```

Thanks for Pavel for pointing this out.